# Stock symbol search engine for Rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search-engine

We're building a finance mobile app with Rails server hosted on Heroku. We need to enable users to search stocks in our database by stock ticker or company name. We also want to show typeahead suggestions. Is there any free Rails search library we can use? Or what's the best (and cheapest) search engine for Rails app on heroku?

We tried yahoo finance api but it shows a lot of stock tickers not in our database. Like http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=GOOG&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback gives you too many results other than "GOOG" and "GOOGL".